# Calling c# methods from GeckoFX C# controll (winforms)

Tags: c#, javascript, html, winforms, geckofx

I want to make an application that uses HTML5 as the UI. The code behind should be written on C#.Net

I have a GeckoFX controll. The thing I want to do is when I click a button/div element in the HTML page, a C# method to be activated.

Here is my idea made-up in code:

HTML

```
<div id="testBtn" onclick="doSomething()">Click for a C# generated message </div>
```

C#

```
void doSomething()
{
//does something in C#
}
```

Comment: You can make an ajax call to the server. But the method would have to have `public static void...` signature and `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than add the event handler using javascript you can add the event handler in C#.

```
<div id="testBtn">Click for a C# generated message </div>
```

C#:

```
browser.DomClick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            switch (args.Target.CastToGeckoElement().GetAttribute("id"))
            {
                case "testBtn":
                    MessageBox.Show("does something in C#");
                    break;
            }
        };
```

Now it would be nice to able to do something like:

browser.Document.GetElementById("testBtn").DomClick += (s,a) => doSomething();

But currently geckofx doesn't have this feature, although it would be possible to add...